# Simple Spring application returning error for route

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have created a simple Spring application with one route at "/a" but when I attempt to access that route, I get an error. The logs show that the route is being mapped, so I am not sure what is causing the error. There is no error message output in the logs.

HomeController.java

```
package com.12345;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

  static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(HomeController.class.getName());

    @RequestMapping("/a")
    public String home() {
    log.debug("a route reached");
        return "Home";
    }
}
```

Application.java

```
package com.12345.config;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.12345")
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Stacktrace and output

```
2016-11-22 10:36:40.512  INFO 644 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@59fd97a8: startup date [Tue Nov 22 10:36:35 PST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-11-22 10:36:40.615  INFO 644 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/a]}" onto public java.lang.String com.12345.HomeController.home()
2016-11-22 10:36:40.620  INFO 644 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2016-11-22 10:36:40.620  INFO 644 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2016-11-22 10:36:40.665  INFO 644 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-11-22 10:36:40.665  INFO 644 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-11-22 10:36:40.717  INFO 644 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-11-22 10:36:41.045  INFO 644 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-11-22 10:36:41.137  INFO 644 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8085 (http)
2016-11-22 10:36:41.144  INFO 644 --- [           main] com.12345.config.Application     : Started Application in 5.751 seconds (JVM running for 6.18)
2016-11-22 10:36:48.217  INFO 644 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-11-22 10:36:48.217  INFO 644 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2016-11-22 10:36:48.242  INFO 644 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 25 ms

===============
localhost:8085/a
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Nov 22 10:47:39 PST 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).

No message available
```

Comment: Which error you get in browser?

Comment: @AlexanderPodkutin : It's the last part of the stacktrace and output snippet (Whitelabel Error Page....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have always used the annotation:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("")
```

On the controller class for accessing the controller and always work.

How about you try:

```
package com.12345;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("")
public class HomeController {

  static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(HomeController.class.getName());

    @RequestMapping("/a")
    public String home() {
    log.debug("a route reached");
        return "Home";
    }
}
```

Then in the application I have:

```
@SpringBootApplication
```

And that should make the trick:

```
package com.12345.config;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.12345")
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Changing the annotation to use RestController instead of Controller seems to have fixed it, but what is the difference between the two?

Comment: I guess the trick is http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html

Comment: "A convenience annotation that is itself annotated with @Controller and @ResponseBody." 
Now I know!

Answer (score 1):

Adding `@ResponseBody` to `home()` should solve it.
Without it, returning "Home" means responding the static file `Home`.

Or, changing `@Controller` to `@RestController` also works. `@RestController` is `@Controller` + `@ResponseBody`.

Comment: Ah I see, so returning "Home" would render the template named "Home"?

Comment: I don't think it's the template. It's just a simple static file. Spring doesn't pre-prosess it.

Comment: No, my misunderstanding. It can be a template.

Answer (score 0):

Here :

```
@RequestMapping("/a")
public String home() {
log.debug("a route reached");
    return "Home";
}
```

Here you return a view named "Home". So you have to have a Home.`ext` where `ext` is the suffix extension used for your view resolver.
If you add `@ResponseBody`, you return the String "Home" as the content of the response. It is totally different.

Answer (score 0):

With the code you are presenting, the request is actually received. Your log statement may have disappeared if you haven't configured your logger to actually log from the debug category.

The error here is the return value of the home() method. It will cause Spring to use your view resolver or if you haven't configured one it will fall back to its default, InternalResourceViewResolver. It will look for the following file "src/main/resources/static/Home" and forward to it as the view. Since it is not found in your case, Spring will try to forward to your error page which is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

please check if your route path is actually http://localhost:8080 by using `servletPath.getRoutePath()`. then continue with your mapping (`/a`) .
this will work.